# How to pass multiple parameters to Crystal Reports using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I used this code to pass a parameter to Crystal Reports, but I can't pass multiple parameters. How can I change this code to pass multiple parameters from C# to Crystal Reports?

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

RPT.RPT_Sale_by_day report = new RPT.RPT_Sale_by_day();
RPT.Form_RPT frm = new RPT.Form_RPT();

report.SetParameterValue("@date1", dt_num1.Value);

frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
frm.ShowDialog();

this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: Have you tried simply putting in more `report.SetParameterValue(paramName, paramValue)` lines?

Comment: Yes , and didn't work

Comment: Not sure if this is the same version (using `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll` myself), but the technique I used was to request the list of parameters from the report itself (`ReportDocument.ParameterFields`), go over them, and detect by `Name` which ones you want to set a value in. I don't remember seeing any @ symbols in these parameter names though.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Initiating created Crystal Report
    ParameterValues  Params =new ParameterValues();            // Creating collection of parameters
    ParameterDiscreteValue Par_Ref =new ParameterDiscreteValue();    // Discrete parameter that comes from SP and shows on Crystal Report

    String PARAMETER1_VALUE ="123";
    String PARAMETER2_VALUE = "ABC";

        Params.Clear();         // Cleaning data collection 
    Par_Ref.Value = PARAMETER1_VALUE; // Assigning discrete value to our variable

    Params.Add(Par_Ref);   //Adding discrete parameter to parameter collection
    report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["PARAMETER1_NAME"].ApplyCurrentValues(Params); //Applying values from our collection to Crystal Report parameters

    Params.Clear();
    Par_Ref.Value = PARAMETER2_VALUE;
    Params.Add(Par_Ref);
    report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["PARAMETER2_NAME"].ApplyCurrentValues(Params);
```

Comment: As many others on here, I don't speak spanish - your comments are of no value to me and the other non-spanish-speakers. It's a good idea to include some Explanation on *why* and *how* your code solves the issue, but please do it in english instead.